# Create Counter of select drop down list with php?

Tags: php

```
<?php 

     //If statement to control pick selection "disabled/enabled"
if(strtotime("Today") == strtotime("Thursday") || strtotime("Friday") ||     strtotime("Saturday") || strtotime("Sunday") || strtotime("Monday")) {
echo '<h2>Make a selection! Picks are now  available</h2>';

$pick = $_POST['teams'];
    if(isset($_POST['teams'])) {
        echo '<br><p>You have made a selection,  feel free to change your pick until ONE HOUR before game time.<p><br>';
    }
}  


?>

  <html>
  <body>

 <h3>Pick</h3>

<div class="loginForm">
<form action="test.php" method="POST">
<fieldset>
<legend>Pick</legend>
<select id="tm1" name="teams">
<option value="null"> Please Select Your Pick</option>
<option value="wr">Washington Redskins</option>
<option value="nyg">New York Giants</option>
<option value="pe">Philadelphia Eagles</option>
<option value="dc">Dallas Cowboys</option>
<option value="br">Baltimore Ravens</option>
<option value="ps">Pittsburgh Steelers</option>
<option value="tt">Tennessee Titans</option>
<option value="gbp">Green Bay Packers</option>
<option value="ss">Seattle Seahawks</option>
<option value="cbr">Cleveland Browns</option>
<option value="bb">Buffalo Bills</option>
<option value="jj">Jacksonville Jaguars</option>
<option value="ic">Indianapolis Colts</option>
<option value="ht">Houston Texans</option>
<option value="kcc">Kansas City Chiefs</option>
<option value="md">Miami Dolphins</option>
<option value="nep">New England Patriots</option>
<option value="nyj">New York Jets</option>
<option value="slr">Saint Louis Rams</option>
<option value="nos">New Orleans Saints</option>
<option value="mv">Minnesota Vikings</option>
<option value="tbb">Tampa Bay Buccaneers</option>
<option value="ac">Arizona Cardinals</option>
<option value="af">Atlanta Falcons</option>
<option value="sf49">San Francisco 49ers</option>
<option value="sdc">San Diego Chargers</option>
<option value="or">Oakland Raiders</option>
<option value="db">Denver Broncos</option>
<option value="cbe">Cincinnati Bengals</option>
<option value="cp">Carolina Panthers</option>
<option value="dl">Detroit Lions</option>
<option value="cbea">Chicago Bears</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
 </fieldset>
 </form>
</div>
```

This is what I have so far, I have created a drop down menu and an almost complete time lock system.
How would I go about creating a counter of every person who submits a selection of a team and display it for every user to see who picked which team? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: There are many ways to do this, but it all depends on what you are trying to accomplish. I suggest you do some research about storage in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

This is NEVER going to work:

```
if(strtotime("Today") == strtotime("Thursday") || strtotime("Friday") ||     strtotime("Saturday") || strtotime("Sunday") || strtotime("Monday")) {
```

That is executed as:

```
   if (foo == (a || b || c || ...))
   if (foo == (non-zero || non-zero || non-zero || ...)
   if (foo == (true || true || true || ...)
   if (foo == true)
```

It should be something more like

```
$days = array(strtotime(...), strtotime(...) , ...);
if (in_array(strtotime('today'), $days) { ... }
```

Comment: Could you explain that alittle more? I figured a better way to go would be through arrays but I wasn't quite sure (still not) of how to do it.